# Trying to understand Parse file storage

Tags: ios, mobile, backend

I have a question about a service called Parse, which is a Backend As A Service (BaaS).

I am not an experienced coder so this is a noob question but I am puzzled by the fact that Parse offers 1 GB of free storage and 10 GB of storage for the $199 plan... it seems to me that Parse would be ridiculously expensive to run an app such as Anypic where user can easily create content which is stored on Parse servers... You would quickly run out of 10 GB even if you don't have a lot of users...

I feel like there is something that I don't understand... If anyone could help me out, I would really be thankful.

PS: I already read all the tutorials and went through the documentation of Parse and tried to ask directly on their forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a scalable solution. The idea would be to start off with the free plan, then whe you get over 1GB you pay 20¢ per extra 1GB. When the combination of your server requests and data storage is large, you move up to the next plan and then when over 10GB you pay 15¢ per extra 1GB. Then you move to enterprise account.

It's expected that if your product does well, you'll be making money so you can pay for the service features you need.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I wanted to use Parse to create an MVP of a photo-sharing app. Do you think that this pricing is too high for my purpose compared to Heroku which is probably not as plug-and-play as Parse but it's probably way cheaper?

Comment: I haven't used Heroku previously and it's pricing looks more complex. Heroku looks more flexible. I think other things than price would really drive the decision between the 2 as they provide very different capabilities / options.

Comment: know this is an old question, but we are using parse for a large photo storage type application and ended up putting the actual image files in AWS S3 and everything else is in PARSE.  To handle security and access we are setting up AWS anonymous TVM, at least that seams the best approach at the moment.